# Has any civilization NOT resisted assimilation by the Borg?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, borg

"We are the Borg, lower your shields, resistance is futile."

'OK, shields are down. We are pacifists. Please come in. Would you like some tea or something while you make drones?'

Has anyone ever not resisted the Borg based on their demand for surrender and/or their reputation as an unstoppable force?

Comment: The Borg have assimilated thousands of species. At least one of them must have surrended

Comment: **Must** have? I could see "quite possibly", but not "must have".

Comment: Probably the Mizar-ians (seen in TNG: Allegiance) would surrender, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @Xantec: Exactly the first species I thought of too.

Comment: How about that alien whose name I forget from The God Complex?

Comment: Any culture not averse to its own destruction is unlikely to survive long enough to be an important part of any civilization.

Comment: Would think that one of the default Borg rules for assimilation worthiness is the species must resist assimilation. They probably give that initial greeting as a test for worthiness.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### TV Canon.

Nope. We only see a vanishingly small number of species actually in the process of being *collectively* assimilated. In each case, those races put up a spirited but futile resistance (and with the exception of humanity and Species 8472, obviously).

### EU Canon

Yes, kinda. In the novel [Star Trek: Voyager - Unworthy](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Unworthy) we meet the Indign. These Borg worshippers have been attempting to contact the Borg (whom they worship as gods) in order to volunteer for assimilation. <s>Un</s>fortunately for them, they were deemed "unworthy" of assimilation and bypassed. By the time we catch up with them, the Borg have been all but wiped out.

> “Or we could remain in the system until the Indign are willing to
>   speak with us again, at which point we tell them the truth,” Willem
>   countered.
>
> “The truth?”
>
> “That the Borg no longer exist. Their master race was conquered by an
>   even greater species and no longer occupies this area of space. Their
>   offerings are no longer necessary.”
>
> “You and I both know that in a situation as delicate as this, sharing
>   that information could prove disastrous.”
>
> “So we simply lie to them by omission? And allow them to go on
>   victimizing other sentient creatures in a cause that has gone from
>   irrationally motivated to absurd? That’s the Starfleet way?” he
>   demanded.
>
> “We have to respect their cultural norms, Admiral. They worship the
>   Borg, the same way humans worshipped gods in any number of forms for
>   thousands of years. It doesn’t matter that those gods are intemperate
>   and ultimately unknowable. That’s part of the allure for those who are
>   so inclined. It’s evidence only of their shortcomings, not those of
>   their gods. It’s the basis for faith.”